# Exchange Hybrid Migration

Tags: email, exchange

Apologies if this question has been answered before. We are going for Exchange hybrid migration to EOL (Exchange Online). On-premise, we have Exchange 2016 mailbox and Exchange 2016 Edge transport servers, DLP appliance (Forcepoint 8.4) and Cisco Email Security as our mail gateway.

We are enabling Centralised Mail Transport (CMT) because we wish to retain the DLP appliance for now until all mailboxes are migrated.

1) When running the HCW, should I choose the Edge Transport server as the Optimal server or the Exchange 2016 mailbox server? The Edge Transport server is used for address-rewrite for outgoing emails. Incoming emails do not traverse the Edge Transport server.

2) Is there any additional configuration needed on the send/receive connectors, so that email delivered to the online mailbox is routed back to the on-premise Exchange (CMT) without issues. I read somewhere that you should not have anything in between the on-premise Exchange and EOL that modifies the email.

3) Is there any address rewriting capabilities in Exchange Online?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Edge server.

2) No. When you add an Edge Transport server to your hybrid deployment, it communicates with EOP on behalf of the internal Exchange servers. The Edge Transport server acts as a relay between the internal Exchange servers and EOP for outbound messaging from the on-premises organization to the Exchange Online organization.

If you need to delete and recreate an Edge subscription that's used to communicate between your on-premises organization and Exchange Online, make sure to run the Hybrid Configuration wizard again.

3)No. We must use Edge server for address rewriting.

Comment: Thanks. The edge transport only processes outgoing emails for address rewriting. So, is it ok to set this one up as the "hybrid server"?

Comment: Thanks Jayce, we have a DLP appliance on prem and most of the users are using IronPort as gateway. That's why I chose Centralised Transport. They are not prepared to decom their legacy stuff at the moment. The Edge server only does outgoing mail. Incoming is straight to the Exchange 2016. We will be turning off the Edge transport server so we will use IronPort for the address rewriting

Answer (score 0):

I have a mail relay between Office 365 and Exchnage on-premise. And could answer to your second question:

> I read somewhere that you should not have anything in between the
>   on-premise Exchange and EOL that modifies the email.

It seems email from cloud to on-premise is treated like external flow. This is because there is a header in the email when it comes from office 365 to on-premise. This header is "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous". It would have been "Internal" if there were a direct connection between EXO and Exchange on-premise. This is because SMTP MAIL FROM command includes XOORG extension that lists EOP TLS certificate, connector setting and accepted domain. Other mail appliances do not understand XOORG. And so mail relay between Office 365 and Exchange on-premise cannot pass it.

Affected systems are room booking, Out of Office external/internal messages.
By default Exchnage allow only internal booking room. So book from cloud to on-premise won't work. Solution is to auto accept invitations from external. You could it set on room by `set-calendarprocessing` command.

More on that https://www.youzou.fr/2019/02/15/advanced-office-365-routing-locking-down-exchange-on-premises-when-mx-points-to-office-365